# how to filter a list in powershell with values

Tags: powershell

I have a list in powrshell consist of ID and Name ,i want to get names with its values but it returns null,here is what I have done

```
foreach ($secret in $secrets) {
$apa = $secret.Name
  }
```

$apa is null,any idea?

Comment: Without showing us how you get that list (from importing a csv perhaps???) it is impossible to answer this

Comment: @Theo thanks,the list is from Docker,and im able to see it i have installed powershell extension in my vs code and when i debug i can see the list contains Name and ID

Comment: Then it looks like your last element in that list does not contain a .Name property. See what you get if you simply do `$secrets.Name`. (should show you an array of all .Name properties in that list)

Comment: @Theo yes it shows,names and values,but the command i run to get the names value returns null ,very irritating

Comment: `names` or `Name`? Big difference. Can you show us the output from `$secrets.GetType().FullName`, and `$secrets |Get-Member`, respectively?

Comment: The problem with your piece of code is that you loop over a list and inside that loop you constantly overwrite the same variable. If the last element does not have the property you're after, then yes.. the variable will be $null. It is still not clear what that list looks like. Are you using the correct property names? Please [edit] your question and show us what you get when you do `$secrets.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ForEach-Object`:

`$secretNames = $secrets |ForEach-Object -MemberName Name`

`$secretNames` now contains all the `Name` values from each individual item in `$secrets`